# Cant access cookies , but can see it getting created on /login but cant access it (JWT , node.js , express)

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, cors

I have made a login route where i generate a jwt and store it in browser cookies, i can see the cookie in my browser application tab and see it getting created in network>req.headers

```
router.post('/login', [
    body('email', 'Enter a valid email').isEmail(),
    body('password', 'Password cannot be empty').exists(),
], async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            console.log('Validation errors:', errors.array());
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const { email, password } = req.body;

        let user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
            console.log('User not found for email:', email);
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: "Enter correct credentials" });
        }

        const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!passwordCompare) {
            console.log('Incorrect password for user:', email);
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: "Enter correct credentials" });
        }

        const data = {
            user: {
                id: user.id
            }
        }

        // Generate auth token
        const token = jwt.sign(data, signature);
        res.status(200).cookie('JWT', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 60 * 1000, secure: true, sameSite: 'None', path: '/' }).json({ success: true, token });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during login:', error);
        return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});
```

when i want to access it here for validation its null,

```
const getCookie = (name) => {
        const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
        const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
        if (parts.length === 2) {
            return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
        }
        return null; // Return null if the cookie is not found
    };


 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Retrieve the token from the cookie
        const token = getCookie('JWT');
        console.log(token);
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const response = await fetch('/api/notes/addnotes', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'JWT': token
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(noteData),
                credentials: 'include'
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                const errorMessage = await response.text();
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}. ${errorMessage}`);
            }

            alert('Memo created successfully');
            setNoteData({
                title: '',
                description: '',
                tag: '',
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error.message);
            alert(`Failed to create memo. ${error.message}`);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };
```

this middleware is to verify the token

```
//middleware
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env' });

const signature = process.env.signature;

const fetchuser = (req, res, next) => {
    // Get the userdetails from the jwt token 
    const token = req.header('JWT');
    console.log('Received token:', token);
    try {
        const data = jwt.verify(token, signature);
        console.log('Token decoded successfully:', data);
        req.user = data.user;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error verifying token:', error);
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Please authenticate using a valid token" });
    }
```

i have checked the naming consitency , network requests , i expect it to get the jwt from cookie and create a note

Comment: A cookie with [`httpOnly: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#httponly) cannot be accessed via the Javascript expression `document.cookie`.